# Convert DateTime from one notation to another

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud

I tried to convert 03/09/2021 00:00:00 to 2021-03-09 00:00:00 using expression transformation

`TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(Date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')`)

But it gives out error:

```
<<Expression Error>> [TO_DATE]: invalid string for converting to Date ... t:TO_DATE(u:TO_CHAR(t:<03/08/2021 00:00:00>,u:'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),u:'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

How can I correct this error?

Comment: A date-time is stored as a single value regardless of the format you choose to display it in. Changing a date to a char and back to a date just gets you back to where you started - so its a pointless exercise.

Comment: So any idea how to get desired result?

Comment: If you just want to display a date in a particular format then use: TO_CHAR(Date, format_string) i.e. just as you have above but without the unnecessary To_DATE

Comment: But TO_Char changes datetime attribute to varchar2, i want final result in datetime only. Any solution to that

Comment: Please can you explain what you are trying to do with this field? A datetime value is stored in your database as (depending on your dbms) something like the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 i.e. as a number. It will be displayed in the default datetime format and you can change how you display it using to_char and a format string. However, regardless of how you display it the value of the underlying number stored in the db doesn't change

Comment: source has datetime in format 03/08/2021 00:00:00 format I just want to change it to 2021/03/08 00:00:00 in target, retaining datatime datatype both in source and target

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure how to explain this any more clearly. '03/08/2021 00:00:00' and '2021/03/08 00:00:00' are stored in a database as exactly the same number e.g. 123456789.9876. How you, or the database, choose to display this value does not change the value stored in the database

Comment: Let me break it down - Inner part of your expression `TO_CHAR(Date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')` is perfect. Then you are trying to convert output of this to a date and thats when the mistake is - you need to provide the format for that. so you are doing this `TO_DATE( exp)` but you need to do this `TO_DATE( exp,''YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'')`. So, pls use this formula `TO_DATE( TO_CHAR(Date,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))`. Now is it needed/worthy, upto you.

Comment: I am sorry, but your expression still gives same error

Comment: Did you understand my previous comment and do you therefore agree that your statement about what you are trying to do ("source has datetime in format 03/08/2021 00:00:00 format I just want to change it to 2021/03/08 00:00:00 in target, retaining datatime datatype both in source and target") is meaningless?

Comment: No I still get same error, I am trying to load entries into salesforce

Comment: So your response shows that you do not understand my comment - I will try again... Type the value 44281.00 into a cell in Excel. Format it as a date in yyyy-mm-dd format; format it as a date in dd/mm/yyyy format; format it as a number. Each of these will DISPLAY the number in a different way but the number stored in Excel never changes. Your database works in exactly the same way: if you store today's date in a field it will be stored as 44281.00; how you choose to display this number doesn't affect how the DB stores the number. Is this any clearer to you?

Comment: I think OP created another question on this topic. @robert, pls fix the formula and it should work. Although i agree with Nick about usability of this expression...